# How to insert a BR tag in JCE?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jce

I am looking for an easy way to add `<br />` tags in **JCE editor**.

When I press enter, it creates either new `<p>` or `<div>` elements, according to the global settings of JCE, which is not what I want.

How to insert **BR** tags in **JCE**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert a `BR` tag in JCE, by pressing: `[SHIFT] + [ENTER]`.
This will create a `<br />` element at the current cursor's position, inside the current container element and will move cursor to the next line.

Also remember, in JCE there is always the **Source Code Editor** view, where you can type/edit directly your html.